# low_memory parameter in read_csv function

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, spyder

What does the `low_memory` parameter do in the `read_csv` function from the pandas library?

Answer (score 1):

This come from the docs themselves. Have you read them?

> low_memory : boolean, default True
>       Internally process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use
>       while parsing, but possibly mixed type inference.  To ensure no mixed
>       types either set False, or specify the type with the `dtype` parameter.
>       Note that the entire file is read into a single DataFrame regardless,
>       use the `chunksize` or `iterator` parameter to return the data in chunks.
>       (Only valid with C parser)

Comment: FYI, this was only added to the docs very recently (and currently only in the development version docs, not in the stable ones), so it is not surprising the OP didn't read it.

Comment: Edit answer to provide the link.